# How to achieve parallax effect with pattern image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimageview, uicolor

I've been trying to achieve parallax effect for an image view. Code for parallax effect is straightforward and it is working only If I add `UIImage` to `UIImageView`. I've a pattern image which needs to tile itself on both sides.

So I had to use `patternWithImage` method of `UIColor`. When I do that parallax working, But I can see the background color of `self.view` in edges when I tilt the device.

Here it is a code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.backgroundImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    self.backgroundImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"connect"]];
    [self addParallaxEffectToView:self.backgroundImageView];
}

- (void)addParallaxEffectToView:(UIView *)view
{
    // Set vertical effect
    UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *verticalMotionEffect =
    [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc]
     initWithKeyPath:@"center.y"
     type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongVerticalAxis];
    verticalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(-50);
    verticalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @(50);

    // Set horizontal effect
    UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *horizontalMotionEffect =
    [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc]
     initWithKeyPath:@"center.x"
     type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongHorizontalAxis];
    horizontalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(-50);
    horizontalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @(50);

    // Create group to combine both
    UIMotionEffectGroup *group = [UIMotionEffectGroup new];
    group.motionEffects = @[horizontalMotionEffect, verticalMotionEffect];

    // Add both effects to your view
    [view addMotionEffect:group];
}
```

Code can be in Swift or Objective-C. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT:**
As per @Clafou suggestion, I'm getting a weird look when I try to push and pop animations.

[image]

Comment: Have you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544402/moving-an-image-with-ios-7-parallax-effect?
I have not tried, so don't know whether it will solve your problem or not.

Comment: I'm confused by your edit! What do you mean by "when I try to push and pop animations"? Would you be able to add an animated GIF to show what happens in motion?

Comment: If you have changed your views to stretch outside the bounds of the root view, I think you may want to to set self.view.clipsToBounds = true in viewDidLoad to not show those parts during view controller transitions.

Comment: @Stefan that did the trick. I totally forgot to give that to self.view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that your `backgroundImageView` needs to extend beyond the edges of its container since your effect will shift it.

As a quick test, if you don't use AutoLayout you could add `self.backgroundImageView.frame = CGRectInset(self.backgroundImageView.frame, -50, -50);` to the end of viewDidLoad.

If you use AutoLayout, change your constraints to make `backgroundImageView` extend beyond its container's frame.